# How to save PDF as BLOB in MongoDB Node app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, pdf

I am creating a node App. I need to save **PDF** in `mongoDB`, i am facing issues achieving this.

Currently i am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload the PDF to server and [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) on node to store it on the server. Then, i save the location of the PDF in Mongo Document.

But, what i want is to store the file directly as a BLOB in the document, not 'file location in server'. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Controller**

```
$scope.upload = function (file)
{
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'uploadImage',
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

**Node - Multer**

```
router.all('/uploadMulter',function (req,res,next) {
   upload(req,res,function(err) {
       if(err) {
           console.log('Error uploading file');
           return res.end("Error uploading file.");
       }
       console.log('success');
       res.end("File is uploaded");
   });
});
```

Comment: Anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Read file using blob and take data in binary format and push in db.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? Explain a bit more.?

Comment: Please go through this -

http://blog.andrewvc.com/node-js-and-binary-data/

https://recalll.co/app/?q=node.js%20-%20Send%20PDF%20file%20from%20AngularJS%20to%20NodeJS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data